# Android reading php

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to make an Android app that reads some data from a php page and put it into a textview.

I already tested it yesterday and it worked! but I dont know what i changed so today it wont work.. 
(I am sure that I dont used async tasks or something like this)

```
package com.example.test04;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String url = "this is the url ";
    private TextView textView;
    private Thread thread;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView2);
    // runthread();
    try{
        textView.setText("");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line ="";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replace("\\n", "\n");
            textView.append(line);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag1234", "Error converting result ===  " + e.toString());
    }
}}
```

after that I tried it with runOnUiThread but it also dont works

```
    //
//  private void runThread() {
//
//      new Thread() {
//          public void run() {
//             
//                  try {
//                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//
//                          @Override
//                          public void run() {
//                              try{
//                                  textView.setText("");
//                                  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
//                                  HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
//                                  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
//                                  
//                                  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
//                                  
//                                  String line ="";
//                                  while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
//                                      line = line.replace("\\n", "\n");
//                                      textView.append(line);
//                                      
//                                  }
//                                  
//                              } catch (Exception e) {
//                                  Log.e("log_tag1234", "Error converting result ===  " + e.toString());
//                              }
//                          }
//                      });
//                   
//                  } catch (Exception e) {
//                      e.printStackTrace();
//                  }
//              
//          }
//      }.start();
//  }
```

how can I fix it as easy as possible? why it doesnt work anymore?

Comment: Don't perform network tasks on the UI thread. You really should use Asynctasks or something like that :)

Comment: but why did it work yesterday?

Comment: I guess your request took longer today, or you changed some code to make it not work.

Comment: Is it throwing any exceptions? If so, what is it?

Comment: network on main thread exception. btw the php site is just a little text that shouldnt take to long to load

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception Move it to an Asynctask.

Comment: ANY network comms on the main thread will cause that exception. Don't do it.

Comment: can you show me how to use the async task? i never used it before